# `You can also now` vs `You can now"

Tags: difference

I always read some statement like this :

- You can also now use feature in product Y
- You can also now listen to songs from the X station
- You can also now download our music on XYZ

Just google using with the double quote "You can also now" you will find it is used all over the place.

It is also possible to say

- You can now/also use feature in product Y
- You can now/also listen to songs from the X station

But are above sentences/statement appropriate on a Website, which the say features/offer is known afterwards?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. It's not very clear what you are asking, as *now/also* with a slash means something different from *now also* or *also now*, but for what it's worth, both sound very unnatural; *you can also use feature X now* or *you can also download our music now* is how I would formulate them.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can also... is the right word order. Indications of time like "now"
are placed at the beginning or the end of a sentence. If you want to learn proper English invest in a good grammar book, don`t rely on Google alone. I am not a teacher, I`m a fellow learner of English.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I would say it is idiomatic.

Comment: @user3169 when there is 1.9 millions search result return from google, a better explanation is needed.